# Prove that if there is a surjective homomorphism from $S_n$ onto $C_r$, then $r$ must be $1$ or $2$.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that if there is a surjective homomorphism from $S_n$ onto $C_r$, then $r$ must be $1$ or $2$. I searched this on google, there is a proof using commutator subgroup, unfortunately, i don't know what it is. Here it a link:http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=36542

Comment: Hint: For $n\ge 3$, $S_n$ is non abelian.

Answer (score 1):

We need a lemma, you can verify this by yourself: **Every permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of 2-cycles**.

let $t$ be a 2-cycle in $S_n$, then $o(\phi(t))|o(t)$, so $o(\phi(t))$ can only be $1$ or $2$, and $\phi(t)=\pm1 \in C_r$. As a general $g\in G$ can written as a product of 2-cycles $t_i$'s, $\phi(g)=\prod_{i} (\pm1)=\pm1$. Since it is surjective, this forces $r=1, 2$.

Comment: why $\phi(t)=+-1$?

Comment: @ Ripan Saha, all other elements in $C_r$ have orders other than 1 or 2.

Comment: Take $C_6$ then the element 2 is of  order 3....

Comment: $C_6$ is the set of 6th roots of unit, which is isomorphic to $Z_6$ (I think you are thinking about $Z_6$ here)

Comment: sorry I was taking $Z_6$..anyway thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $S_n$ onto $C_r$ (cyclic group of order r).  Then r is 1 or 2.
If n is 1 or 2, it's clear.  So assume $n\geq3$.  Let K be the kernel of $\phi$.  Then $K\neq <1>$ since $S_n$ is not cyclic.  If $K\cap A_n=<1>$, $S_n=KA_n$ ($S_n/A_n$ has order 2) and then K would be of order 2 and $K\subseteq Z(S_n)$, but $Z(S_n)=<1>$.  So $K\cap A_n\neq <1>$.  Now suppose $n\ne4$.  Since $A_n$ is simple, $A_n\subseteq K$.  So the order of $G/K$ divides the order of $G/A_n=2$.  Suppose n=4.  Then r is at most 4 since the maximum order of an element of $S_4$ is 4.  If r were 4, K would have order 6 and so a Sylow 3 subgroup of $S_4$ would be normal in $S_4$, but there are 3 Sylow 3 subgroups of $S_4$.  If r were 3, K would have order 8, impossible since $S_4$ has 3 Sylow 2 subgroups.  Hence r is 1 or  2.